# flex responder default timeout value?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Does anyone knows whats the default timeout value for the responder object? is there a time limit when the flex app will wait for result and call fault handler instead of result handler?

Answer (score 2):

Use the getter / setter to access the requestTimeOut property of your RemoteObject.

More info here: [RemoteObject](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/rpc/remoting/RemoteObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

First off... I would recommend setting a cfquery timeout in any cfc call (if you're using coldfusion). If the query times out then it will hit your fault.

Check out "requestTimeout" here
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/rpc/remoting/RemoteObject.html#propertySummary

You can also just create your own timer with a timer object 
Once the timer reaches a certain point you can "disconnect" or "logout", and call the fault function manually

Let me know if this helps.